# global variable doesn't work when I use exec

Tags: python, methods, exec, eval, global

Whenever I execute my code with following snippet, it works perfectly fine.

```
def set_globvar_to_one():
    global globvarq
    globvarq = 2

def print_globvar():
    print(globvarq)

set_globvar_to_one()
print_globvar()
```

But, in my case, I need to execute this snippet using exec command as my code is dynamic.
So, I tried following.

```
def set_globvar_to_one():
    exec(compile("global globvarq","setglobal","exec"))
    exec(compile("globvarq = 2","setglobal","exec"))
def print_globvar():
    eval(compile("print(globvarq)","setglobal","eval")) 

set_globvar_to_one()
print_globvar()
```

and this code is throwing following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    print_globvar()
    eval(compile("print(globvarq)","setglobal","eval"))
  File "setglobal", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'globvarq' is not defined
```

How can I make the variable global from one method and use the same variable in another method?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why this is failing, but I can point out that compiling & executing a `global` statement by itself is utterly useless - it cannot have any effect on a separately-compiled statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're actually trying to achieve, but this does what you expected:

```
def set_globvar_to_one():
    exec(compile("global globvarq\nglobvarq = 2", "setglobal", "exec"))


def print_globvar():
    eval(compile("print(globvarq)", "setglobal", "eval"))


set_globvar_to_one()
print_globvar()
```

Comment: This is working as I expected. However, why is my code is not working? both looks same to me :/

Comment: A key difference is that the two lines in the first function are a single piece of code and thus executed in context of each other - `globvarq` wasn't global in the second `exec()` statement, being 'global' isn't a property of a value, it's the property of the local name referring to a value.